# Can anyone help source a quote. Something like, “Even gears are for concrete mixers.”

Tags: racing, road, europe, bike-culture

I feel like I heard this quote from an old school cyclist, like a Belgian who spent a lot of years wearing a poncho or some such. I could also swear that I found the source of the quote a few years ago but I just can’t find a trace of it. My Google fu is usually pretty good, but it’s failing me on this one.

Comment: Nope.   A good while googling returns nothing relevant except this question.   Was it in the context of "even-numbered gears" or "all gears" ?   Was it in favour of odd numbers of gears, or odd ratios, or only single speeds?

Comment: Is there any chance you are thinking Henri Desgranges’ quote about how derailleurs were only for people over age 45? (Yes, Desgranges is French not Belgian.)

Comment: @Criggie Multiples of 2, or not odd. Basically only ride odd numbered ratios or only have odd number cogs on your cassette.

Comment: I know the quote is about a bicycle, but the question is about a quotation.  Not sure where else you could try asking - Skeptics.SE wants a claim to verify so that's a bad match.  History.SE isn't about quotes, neither is English.SE   We might have to leave the question open for a long time to get any answers.